# Epson negatives scan error

Tags: film, 35mm, negative-film, scanner, epson

I have an Epson V330 scanner, after long time sitting unused I took it to scan a few negatives. First few scans were okay but then strange stripes appeared, sometimes stripes goes all over negative, sometimes it's a green matrica-a-like thing. What could be the reason? [image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using a different cable to connect the scanner to your computer?

Comment: Your film is not straight. Are you using a holder designed to scan 35mm film? Also, what are your software setting, what software, and what version?